# Using Cortex-M4 hardware support to compute CRC32

Tags: arm, crc, crc32

I'm working on code to compute CRC32 using the hardware CRC support that's built into the ARM Cortex-M4 processor.  For reference, there's an application note that describes the hardware here:

http://www.st.com/st-web-ui/static/active/en/resource/technical/document/application_note/DM00068118.pdf

Basically, you write 32-bits of data at a time to a memory-mapped register (CRC_DR), and then you read the resulting CRC back from the same address. However, the CRC this produces is quite different than the standard result that the software CRC32 libraries produce. I finally found someone who had written code that manipulates the Cortex result to produce the "standard" result:

http://www.cnblogs.com/shangdawei/p/4603948.html

My code (shown below and adapted from the above solution) now produces the "standard" result, but I suspect there are more calls to function ReverseBits than are actually necessary. I'm hoping someone can tell me if it can be simplified.

Thanks!
Dan

```
#define RCC_BASE    0x40023800
#define RCC_AHB1ENR *((uint32_t *) (RCC_BASE + 0x30))

#define CRC_BASE    0x40023000
#define CRC_DR      *((volatile uint32_t *) (CRC_BASE + 0x00))
#define CRC_IDR     *((volatile uint32_t *) (CRC_BASE + 0x04))
#define CRC_CR      *((volatile uint32_t *) (CRC_BASE + 0x08))

uint32_t ARMcrc32(void *data, uint32_t bytes)
{
uint32_t *p32 = data ;
uint32_t crc, crc_reg ;

RCC_AHB1ENR |= 1 << 12 ;    // Enable CRC clock

CRC_CR |= 0x00000001 ;      // Reset the CRC calculator

while (bytes >= 4)
    {
    CRC_DR = ReverseBits(*p32++) ;
    bytes -= 4 ;
    }
 crc_reg = CRC_DR ;
 crc = ReverseBits(crc_reg) ;

 if (bytes > 0)
    {
    uint32_t bits = 8 * bytes ;
    uint32_t xtra = 32 - bits ;
    uint32_t mask = (1 << bits) - 1 ;

    CRC_DR = crc_reg ;

    CRC_DR = ReverseBits((*p32 & mask) ^ crc) >> xtra ;
    crc = (crc >> bits) ^ ReverseBits(CRC_DR);
    }

return ~crc ;
}
```

Comment: This looks like a good candidate for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/!

Comment: Note there is no "CRC support that's built into the ARM Cortex-M4 processor", this is ST's peripheral built into ST's STM32 microcontrollers (as the appnote hints, it's available across at least the whole F family, which now encompasses 4 different CPU cores). Given that this is pure C code, it's basically irrelevant what CPU happens to be in the micro anyway. What matters a lot more is what actual micro it is, because if it's an F3 or F7 then you should also be able to simply reprogram the polynomial to whichever other one of the dozens of "standard" values you want, and not need this at all.

Comment: Quite right - my mistake. And yes, I wish I had an F3 or F7. :-)